# Setting up a web server, using multiple user accounts

Tags: users, webserver, virtualhost

I’ve just installed Ubuntu Server on a new server and have been looking around for tutorials on setting up a web server with multiple user accounts.

How I’ve set small web servers like this in the past is the same way most of the tutorials suggest, by creating directories within `/var/www/` and then using Apache virtual hosts to redirect the traffic.

What I’m trying to do is create a system whereby the user accounts are setup under `/home/new_account/`, and then the `public_html` directory is within that, which is where the virtual hosts links to.

Is it as simple as that? If I wanted to automate it from a control panel, can I create accounts easily using, say PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to enable the `userdir` module for apache

`sudo a2enmod userdir`

And restart apache (`sudo service apache2 restart`)

If you need to use php as well inside the user directories :

```
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo a2enmod php5
```

Open `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf` and remove/comment the following lines :

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_value engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

After this, everything you put in `~/public_html` will automatically be available at `http://example.com/~username`.
Make sure you are aware of the security issues involved before you do this (especially the php part)

**Source:** [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UserDirectoryPHP)

Comment: That’s perfect, thanks for the help @Capt.Nemo - it’s only for internal/local network use, security risk is _reduced_ a little.